# Cual seria la ip destino para abrir un puerto TCP?

Tags: redes, puertos, ip, windows-server, firewall

contrate un servicio vps, y para abrir un puerto (3050) me piden que rellene un formulario ya que no me permite hacerlo desde el Windows Server, los datos solciitados son : Ip origen, mascara, ip destino, mascara, protocolo (tcp, udp) y numero de puerto.

Estoy algo confuso con lo de ip destino...

Alguna solucion? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abrir un puerto puede ser para entrada o salida. Imaginate un router en tu domicilio.

Generalmente los puertos de salida suelen estar todos abiertos, por ejemplo el T:80 para navegar o el T:21 para FTP. pero algunos proveedores, o empresas pueden bloquear ciertos puertos para que no se tenga disponibles ciertas funcionalidades. En la salida además debes usar NAT generalmente

En la entrada, no solo puede estar bloqueada, sino que si un router actúa como proxi, además tenes que decir el puerto donde entra, por ejemplo, si tenes un servidor WEB (Puerto T:80) en la dirección .22, y tenes varias otros dispositivos que navegan a través del router, tenes que decirle que esa entrada T:80 debe ir a la ip .22.

Ahora tus preguntas:

**IP Origen**: Si es de salida, es la IP interna de la computadora que quiere salir. Si es de entrada, es la IP publica externa fija que quiere entrar a tu red.

**Mascara origen**: Es lo que determina si es una, varias o todas las IPs que Quieren salir, o entrar. (Genera la conexión)

**IP Destino**: Justo al reves de la IP origen, Si es salida, es la IP Publica fija a la que te vas a conectar, si es entrada, es la IP de tu red interna que recibirá el paquete (comunicación) entrante.

**Mascara destino**: Igual que la mascara origen, pero justo al reves, si es entrante o saliente. (Destino de la conexión, generalmente es una sola, controlalo).

**Protocolo**:, ya te lo respondiste, si es TCP, UDP, otros, ambos, etc.

**Puerto/s**: El o los puertos que se abren para entrar o salir. (Si es TCP o UDP)